# error: 1054, "Unknown column 'daily_distance_per_dollar' in 'field list'

Tags: mysql, sql

I am looking to find the absolute difference between the  daily distance per dollar and the monthly average distance per dollar. Link to the question: https://platform.stratascratch.com/coding/10302-distance-per-dollar?code_type=3

I have tried the following

```
WITH
ct1 AS (
    SELECT *,
    DATE_FORMAT(
    uber_request_logs.request_date,
    '%Y-%m'
    ) AS MONTH,
    (
     uber_request_logs.distance_to_travel 
    / uber_request_logs.monetary_cost
    ) AS daily_distance_per_dollar
    FROM
        uber_request_logs
    ),
ct2 AS (
    SELECT
    MONTH,
    AVG(ct1.daily_distance_per_dollar)
    OVER(PARTITION BY MONTH) AS average_distance_per_dollar
    FROM ct1
    )
SELECT
MONTH,
AVG(
    ABS(
        daily_distance_per_dollar - average_distance_per_dollar
    )
) AS answer
FROM
ct2
GROUP BY MONTH
```

I want to do it with CTE or at least understand what's my mistake here for the above error.

Answer (score 0):

You don’t have a column called daily_distance_per_dollar in ct2.

You probably need to change

```
AVG(ct1.daily_distance_per_dollar)
```

to

```
AVG(ct1.daily_distance_per_dollar) as daily_distance_per_dollar
```